# Intel RDSEED 64 only giving 5 bytes of data

Tags: c, rdrand

I'm trying to generate 8 bytes of random data using RDSEED (to seed SecureRandom in Java), by getting the 8 bytes from the 64-bit unsigned integer it generates. The problem is, while testing my code, I noticed that there are always 3 bytes that are zero, no matter how much I run the application.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

uint64_t rdseed64() {
    int retries = 0;
    uint64_t result;
    while (!_rdseed64_step(&result) || retries < 10) {
        retries++;
    }
    return result;
}

uint8_t* getBytes() {
    uint64_t x = rdseed64();
    uint8_t *p;
    p = (uint8_t *)&x;
    uint8_t buf[8];
    buf[0] = p[7];
    buf[1] = p[6];
    buf[2] = p[5];
    buf[3] = p[4];
    buf[4] = p[3];
    buf[5] = p[2];
    buf[6] = p[1];
    buf[7] = p[0];
    return buf;
}
int main(void) {
    uint8_t* bytes = getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        uint8_t byte = bytes[i];
        printf("%x ", byte);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:
`d4 0 0 0 fb 2c 5e 7e`
`7e 0 0 0 89 5e 76 a2`
`97 0 0 0 bd f 65 30`

Comment: `while (!_rdseed64_step(&result) || retries < 10)` - why `||` ?

Comment: Why do you want to reverse bytes of random data?

Comment: `return buf;` - this is your culprit though - you are returning a local array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, I changed the parameters of the function to pass a uint8_t array (and fill it with random bytes), and it worked. I'll mark this question as solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Code not compiled with all warnings enabled**

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

Save time.
Try, if using gcc:

```
-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion
```

**Invalid pointer**

`getBytes()` returns a pointer to an object that is no longer in existence.  Result : *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
int8_t* getBytes() {
    ...
    uint8_t buf[8];
    ...
    return buf;
}
```

I recommend to instead pass into `getBytes()` a pointer to valid memory to store  the 8 bytes.  Rewrite `getBytes()` to accept that pointer.

```
uint8_t bytes[8];
getBytes(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I was returning a local array. I rewrote the function to take a uint8_t array as a parameter, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).